# String Replace() giving null pointer exception

Tags: java

Where Iam Going Wrong?? No Matter What I do It Says Null Pointer Exception on String.replace() 
I want To replace a Charecter From File And Write The Changed Content To Other File.. even though its easy i am unable to write it.Help Please!

```
package tinku;
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author gajasurve
 */
public class Tinku {
    static int i;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String str;

        final String Y;
        String Key;
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/home/gajasurve/Desktop/done2.txt");
        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(fos);
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("\n Enter Complete File Path with Extension  (ex: /home/gajasurve/Desktop/info.txt)  : ");
        String Source;
        Source=r.readLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Key Element to Find In the File ");
        Key=r.readLine();   
        File f= new File(Source);   
        LineNumberReader lr= new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(f));

        while((str=lr.readLine())!=null)
        {
            if(str.contains(Key))
            {
                i=lr.getLineNumber();
                System.out.print("The Entered Key Element Can B Found In " + i + "   Line");
            } 
        }

        System.out.println("Do u wish to change the Key Element? Y|N");
        String Dec= r.readLine();
        switch (Dec) {
            case "Y" :     
                System.out.print("Enter New Key Element to Replace");
                String d2;
                d2 = r.readLine();
                str= str.replaceAll(Key, d2);  //NPE here
                System.out.println(str);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you run your while loop, the exit condition is that the loop ends when `str` becomes `null`, hence when you are trying to access `str` the next time it is null and so gives a `NullPointerException`.

You can fix it by running a similar `while` loop around the `replaceAll()` code, or you can move everything until the `replaceAll()` method call inside the `while` loop. (Note: this will ask if you want to replace the `Key` for every occurrence)

Possible Fixed Code:

```
package tinku;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import java.io.*;

/**
 *
 * @author gajasurve
 */
public class Tinku {
    static int i;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String str;

        final String Y;
        String Key;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("\n Enter Complete File Path with Extension (ex: /home/gajasurve/Desktop/info.txt)  : ");
        String Source;
        Source = br.readLine();

        File f= new File(Source);
        LineNumberReader lr= new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(f));

        System.out.print("Enter Key Element to Find In the File : ");
        Key = br.readLine();

        while((str = lr.readLine()) != null) {
            if(str.contains(Key)) {
                i = lr.getLineNumber();
                System.out.println("The Entered Key Element Can B Found In " + i + " Line");
            } 
        }

        lr.close();

        System.out.println("Do u wish to change the Key Element? Y|N");
        String Dec= br.readLine();
        switch(Dec) {
            case "Y" : {
                System.out.print("Enter String to replace Key with : ");
                String d2;
                d2 = br.readLine();
                lr= new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(f));
                String outputFile = "/home/gajasurve/Desktop/done2.txt";
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));

                while((str = lr.readLine()) != null) {
                    if(str.contains(Key)) {
                        pw.println(str.replaceAll(Key, d2));
                    } else {
                        pw.println(str);
                    }
                }
                pw.close();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So How Can I Fix It??

Comment: why don't you assign the str value inside if block in a variable

Comment: Edited answer, accept the answer if it solved your problem, else add your doubts as comments.
We can't just assign the value of `str` to a variable as there might be multiple occurrences. We would need a list to store all of them.

Comment: @Codi I don't get it why we can't ?

Comment: @theRoot Say we are looking for the `key`="hello", and the file has 2 lines, containing "hello world 1" and "hello world 2", then if we store `str` in a variable say `storage`, then the first time it would store "hello world 1", but when "hello world 2" is also read as a positive case, then it will overwrite `storage` by storing "hello world 2" in it. In that case we lose the previous value which had to be replaced, hence we will need to use a list to store all the occurrences.

Comment: @Codi Thanku For Such a Speed Reposne.. i am trying to replace a content of file to another file as u can see the code.. But It Isnt working... Can u write me a working model of it please so that i can actually look and learn what u did.. Please? i know its too much to as but.. Help!

Comment: @GajaSurve What do you need, if `Key` occurs in the file, do we need to replace it with the same String everywhere, or do we need to ask what to change it to each time ?

Comment: @Codi if Key Occurs in file it Should as to Replace it with Some other Key. No Need to Ask Everytime ReplaceAll() Will Do.. And If Possible Please Keep The Code Simple So that I can Learn from it :)

Comment: @Codi and It Should Show The Line Number Where The Key Has been Found Which we Will b replacing.. Thnak u :)

Comment: @Codi Bro No need to Code :) ur Fixed Code Just Works Fine.. thank u .. Thnak u So much :)

Comment: it would b great if u Write the same solution Using Tokenizers?

Comment: I think `contains() ` is better than tokenizers as we do not know if the Key we are looking for is a word or 2 words or part of a word, in other words, the key may not be a token, and finding a suitable delimiter would be difficult. @GajaSarve Accept the answer if it helped you. Thanks

Comment: @Codi S Brother.. it helped a lot. i would like to Thank u :)